# Using the Terraform Docker Provider with a DigitalOcean droplet resource

Tags: docker, terraform

I am using Terraform to create Digital Ocean droplets, and I would like to use the Docker provider to set up my app after the droplet is created, however, I can't configure the Docker provider to use the droplet:

```
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "dev" {
  ...
}

provider "docker" {
  host = "ssh://devops@${digitalocean_droplet.dev.ipv4_address}" # <-- this fails
}
```

I can't interpolate the address of the created droplet inside the provider block, I get the following error:

```
Error: Error initializing Docker client: unable to parse docker host ``
```

How could I get this working?

Comment: Which docker provider are you using?

Comment: https://registry.terraform.io/namespaces/kreuzwerker… Is there any other?

Comment: Yes there are many others. If you typed "docker" into the search box on that same page you linked, it would take you to a list of docker providers: https://registry.terraform.io/search/providers?q=docker

Comment: Wow! So many clones of the original one…